# I have included string.h but when i try to use it as in the following i get errors

Tags: c++, string, std, member

I have included string.h but when i try to use it as in the following i get errors

```
#include<string.h>
std::string something;
```

here std will be flagged and it says ** error C2039: 'string' : is not a member of 'std'**

But in other parts of my program it works, only in some places i do get this error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct header file for std::string is `string`, not `string.h`.

Comment: that solved it. Thanks! But .... then, why does it work in other parts of my program with the **.h**?

Comment: I would assume the correct header is being pulled in from another header file that's also included and your inclusion of string.h is redundant.

Comment: string.h is the string header from the c-library (whose c++ equivalent would be the cstring header)

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` dos not exist in C.  Probably you want to use C++.